# How to get Item-Quantity map using Spring MVC forms?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

For each dish I have an input to specify the quantity of dishes, but how can I convert it DTO's DishQuantityMap? Where firstInteger - dishId, second - quantity of dishes ordered.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${Order}" method="post">
<span th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
<input id="number" type="number" value="42">
</span>
</form>
```

I know I am missing th:field in my code, that is because I don't know how to implement it properly.

```
public class Order {
    private String userName;
    Map<Integer, Integer> DishQuantityMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `dishList` is, but if it has an `id` field then the code for your form would look something like:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${Order}" method="post">
  <span th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
    <input th:field="*{dishQuantityMap[__${dish.id}__]}" type="number" />
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: I know it's against the rules to write thank you, but you can't even understand how I value the code you wrote above, I tried to do the same for 2 days and nobody knew how to work with maps in Thymeleaf. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please take a look, somehow, my JS just stopped working after adding this line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70817904/js-stopped-working-after-adding-thymeleaf-thfield-why-is-it-so